# Video not autoplaying when i use poster image

Tags: html, html5-video

I have a simple problem.

I want to use an image until the video downloads to cache. And after video download is finished, the video must autoplay. So, I used "poster" attribute  for image. But now video autoplay is not working.

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay loop poster="img/loading.gif">
    <source src="img/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I don't want to use "controls" attribute. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could potentiality be this [Google chrome disables autoplay](https://www.theverge.com/2018/5/3/17251104/google-chrome-66-autoplay-sound-videos-mute)

Chrome and i believe Firefox have disabled autoplay on websites. Users have to allow video's to be autoplayed.